# iPhone: Problem loading images from NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimageview

I have array of image url. I want to show the images into UIImageView.

Now I convert the URL to NSData and then convert that into UIImage and then try to load that into UIImageView.

But it takes a lot of time to do this.

Is there a better way where in I can load the images in a faster and better manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite all of the answers on here telling you to do this in one line of code, it will sadly make no difference to the URL connection speed OR data / image decoding. If you want a faster way to TYPE the code then fine, but I would use category added to UIImageView....

```
@interface UIImageView (URL)

- (void)loadFromUrl:(NSString *)aUrl;

@end

@implementation UIImageView (URL)

- (void)loadFromUrl:(NSString *)aUrl {
  NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:aUrl];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

  if(image != nil) {
    [self setImage:image];
  }
}

@end
```

Now you can include the header and do...

```
[myImageView loadFromUrl:@"http://myurl.com/image.jpg"];
```

For more categories (I will be adding this one to my list!) check [here.](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/) Those are all my useful ones, you may find them useful too! :)

Comment: best thing about this is it can be kept and re-used, across classes and across projects!

Comment: @ Daniel Hanly  , @Simon Lee  :Does it make any difference on the speed of downloading image through URL ?

Comment: No, as I said, sadly not, there is little you can do due to network limitations / bandwidth / image size etc :( ....but I was merely presenting a more re-usable version of making it easier to type.

Comment: it's a matter of comparing `myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/image.jpg"]]];` with `[myImageView loadFromUrl:@"http://myurl.com/image.jpg"];`

Answer (score 1):

Use everything in a single statement.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];
```

Comment: You do realise doing this in ONE statement makes NO difference to the speed of either the URL connection OR the image decoding!?!?

Comment: @Simon Lee : Agree, But in both cases the speed depend on the network Connectivity ..

Comment: This IS a faster way to type it, but not a faster way to process it. I think the OP is talking about a faster processing speed not faster typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

image is UIImage and imageView is UIImageView

```
NSData *receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"yoururl"];
self.image=nil;
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData ];
self.image = img;
[img release];
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];
```